# Getting id after inserting row(Spring boot/JPA)

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have trouble with getting `id` from one `table` after a `new user` is added.

I have 2 tables, the `user` and the other one that has to be joined with the `user` `table` into the `third table` which will contain `id` from those `2 tables`.

For that, I need the `id` of the `second table`, which if I understood correctly have to be collected after `inserting` row.

How to implement that getting id?

Comment: JPA save method returns everything https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#save-S-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define relationship between two entities using `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` annotations. Then calling `save` method from `JpaRepository` on the "one" side will set it's id. Then you just call the `save` method on the "many" side of relation, and related id will be inserted along with the data.
Or, instead of calling `save` on every entity separately, you can set the attribute `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` of `@OneToMany` annotation and then you'll have to call `save` method only on one entity.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
retObject = repository.save(retObject );
repository.flush();
retObject.getId(); // get id here
```